# LeetCode problem number 390, concept of recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I have attempted the question using recursion, everything is going as expected until the end i.e except for the last step when len(arr)==1, where the returned res is reset to 0. After debugging the code, I understand that when the recursion stack is returned to its previous calls, it is resetting the res to 0. But how do we not change it?
I want to understand the recursion concept here, though I know there might be more efficient solutions to this problem

```
class Solution:
def lastRemaining(self, n: int) -> int:
    run_number=1
    arr=[x for x in range(1,n+1)]
    res=0
    def helper(arr,run_number,res):
        
        
        if len(arr)==1:
            res=arr[0]
            print(type(res))
            print(res)
            return res
        elif run_number%2==1:
            arr = [v for i, v in enumerate(arr) if i % 2 == 1]
            print(arr)
            run_number+=1
            helper(arr,run_number,res)

        else:
            arr = [v for i, v in enumerate(arr) if i % 2 == 0]
            print(arr)
            run_number+=1
            helper(arr,run_number,res)
    print(type(helper))        
    x=helper(arr,run_number,res)
    return x
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return your recursion calls.
I removed the prints and added them for you also; the way you deleted the values from left to right was wrong, so I changed it

this code still cant pass all of the tests (got 3373 / 3377) since it doesn't run O(n^2) efficiently if it fails for large numbers due to time limits

but if you insist on solving this question with recursion, I think this is the way (or at least the way that looks the most similar to your original solution )

I hope I could help :) feel free to ask me anything in the comments

```
class Solution(object):
    def lastRemaining(self, n: int) -> int:
        run_number=1
        arr=[x for x in range(1,n+1)]
        res=0
        def helper(arr,run_number,res):

            
            if len(arr)==1:
                res=arr[0]
                return res
            elif run_number%2==1:
                arr = erase_from_right(arr)
                run_number+=1
                return helper(arr,run_number,res) #return added here
            else:
                arr = erase_from_left(arr)
                run_number+=1
                return helper(arr,run_number,res) #return added here 

        
        def erase_from_right(arr):
            return [v for i, v in enumerate(arr) if i % 2 == 1]
    
        def erase_from_left(arr):
            new_arr=[]
            while(arr):
                arr.pop()
                if(arr):
                    new_arr.insert(0,arr.pop())                    
            return new_arr
        
        x=helper(arr,run_number,res)
        return x
```